# Simple loop is too slow

Tags: algorithm, scala, complexity-theory

I don't understand why the following code is too slow. The goal of this code is pretty simple : I have a set of points which I want to split in 6 buckets (so 100000 points per bucket). The code :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map, ListBuffer}
object Main {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    val m : Map[String, ListBuffer[Double]] = Map()
    val labels = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6")
    val points = Array.fill(600000){0.0}
    var it = 0
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
    for (i <- 0 until points.length) {
      if(it == labels.length-1) it = 0
      val point = points(i)
      val currentLabel = labels(it)
      val values = m.getOrElse(currentLabel, ListBuffer())
      m += (currentLabel -> (values :+ point))
      it += 1
      println("it -> = " + it)

    }
    val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
    println("fill values in = " +  (t2-t1) + " msecs")
  }
}
```

Access of map and append on a list buffer take a constant time so for me, the complexity of this code is O(n) where n is the number of points to split. Can I have some advices to make this code much faster ?

Comment: Inserting and searching in an immutable map are `O(log n)`, which one are you using?

Comment: working code that needs to be optimized belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I add the imports but I use a mutable Map.

Comment: `m += (currentLabel -> (values :+ point))` is pushing the label back into the map. You only need to add the label/listbuffer once, after that you can just append to the list buffer.

Comment: maybe try prepending instead of appending `(values :+ point)` => `(point +: values)`

Comment: I try your suggestions but it's not make the code much faster :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here (as a separate answer as it's quite different from my first answer) is another "C style" one, that does handle a variable number of buckets.

Interestingly on my machine, it's about twice as fast as the other C-style answer from Espen Brekke. UPDATE: I take that back - both were running so  fast the actual execution time was masked by start up time etc. Running on 100x as many points (60000000), Espen's is about twice as fast (but has a fixed number of buckets) - about 220ms compared to about 420ms

UPDATE2: Espen's latest is now more or less the same as below (except using an exception instead of an explicit bounds check) and, not surprisingly, runs at a similar speed.

Also note that neither version times the creation of the bucket arrays. On my machine, that's about another 200ms (for either version), so about 50%-100% of the time it takes to put things in the buckets...

This variant, therefore, is about 100,000 times faster than the OP's original code (on my machine)!

```
object buckets2 extends App {

 val labels = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6")
val points = Array.fill(600000){0.0}

val count = 6
val bucket_size = ((points.length-1)/count) + 1 

val buckets = Array.fill(count) (new Array[Double](bucket_size));

var b = 0
val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis

while (b < count) {
  var i = b
  var j  = 0
  val this_bucket = buckets(b)
  while (i < points.length) {
    this_bucket(j) =  points(i)
    i = i + count
    j = j + 1
  }
  b = b + 1

}

val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis

println("fill values in = " +  (t2-t1) + " msecs")

}
```

Comment: Your solution is the faster, thank you and now, I will be careful between a FP solution and non FP solution to such problems :)

Comment: There's the old adage "if it doesn't have to return the correct answer, I can make it run as fast as you like".  I find the more FP approaches much better at getting me to the right answer than if I start with a maximal-performance-mindset. And often, the FP performance is fine as it's not the bottleneck. So "make it right, then make it fast (if needed)"

Answer (score 6):

The following refactoring does not incur in creating as many collections as points, and relies in Scala API,

```
object Main {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    val labels = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6")
    val points = Array.fill(600000){0.0}

    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
    val xst = points.grouped(labels.size).toArray.transpose
    val m = (labels zip xst).toMap
    val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis

    println("fill values in = " +  (t2-t1) + " msecs")
  }
}
```

While the original code takes minutes, this one took some 700 msecs.

This code avoids indexed referencing and updating existing collections.

**Update with the code that I fill the memory (Alifirat)**

```
object Main {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    val labels = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6", "7")
    val points = Array.fill(7000000){0.0}

    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
    val xst = points.grouped(labels.size).toArray.transpose
    val m = (labels zip xst).toMap
    val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis

    println("fill values in = " +  (t2-t1) + " msecs")
  }
}
```

Same code but run on 7 000 000 points for 7 buckets.

**Update**

Try

```
scala -J-Xmx4g
```

and then paste the updated code.

**Update**

Should the final map map onto arrays of `0.0`, the following proves pretty fast on 70 million points,

```
val m = labels.map(l => l -> Array.fill(10*1000*1000){0.0}).toMap
```

In case performance is essential, C-oriented approaches as already suggested my prove memory and time efficient, possibly at the expense of scalability and compositionality.

Comment: Nice catch with `grouped`. I always keep forgetting about its existance

Comment: Thank you for the response, the reason why I didn't use `grouped` it's because this code crash if the number of points is greater than one million.

Comment: @alifirat If you look at `grouped` implementation (`groupBy` almost the same), you'll find out that its implementation is exactly the same you were trying to do. It constructs mutable builder inside and adds value to it. Only that it doesn't do empty inserts when you did them, so it actually much faster. There is no way it can crash if your code didn't. You probably coded something in a wrong way

Comment: @alifirat I do not get your point. Is this your code it fails with? It is exactly the code proposed by `elm`, but with an additional element. What exception do you receive?

Comment: @alifirat And I don't think you should edit others answer to ask an additional question - this is not an answer. Please send the gist in the comments or edit your own question

Comment: Sorry for the update and what I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I took the same example, adding a label and the number of points is 7 000 000 now.

Comment: No problem, pedagogical insights in any case :)

Comment: @alifirat That's actually weird. I can compute 70m with this code and my jvm goes up to 3 gb, which is less that you've set. Anyway, are you sure you can compute THAT amount with your original code? This is completely another question, and `grouped` has nothing to do with it. `grouped` is quite efficient in its way. You may really have some increase in memory due to FP style copying your collections, but I don't think it should ever be bigger than 2x. In case if you want to compute amounts that do not fit into your heap - you may want to chunk your data

Comment: You can also try to use `view` to decrease the amount of memory consumed

Comment: Like you said, it's weird for me and this is why I ask this question here. Like you, I try a simple code (with and without FP style) but past millions of points, the JVM does not support that.

Comment: @alifirat I see. Not sure I can add anything more, so I'll retreat :) If you find out that procedure-style approach works better for you, you can just use your code and remove `values += point` and change `getOrElse` to `getOrElseUpdate`. Or try all the solutions in this thread and choose the better one, there are quite a lot of alternatives here so you might just test every for memory/performance consumption and use the best

Answer (score 2):

Another way of skinning the cat:

```
val buckets = Array.fill(labels.length)(ArrayBuffer.empty[Double])
points.zipWithIndex.foreach{case(p, i) => buckets(i%labels.length) += p}
(labels zip buckets).toMap
```

I've not benchmarked it properly, but it's the fastest thing I've tried (not any more - see my other answer)

Answer (score 1):

As @Noah correctly noticed in the comments, you don't have to push the buffer back to the map. This should be enough:

```
val values = m.getOrElseUpdate(currentLabel, ListBuffer())
values += point
```

Or you could do it with a functional approach, which is recommended if you work with scala:

```
val labels = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6")
val points = Array.fill(60000){2.0}
val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
val m = points.zipWithIndex.groupBy {
  case (point, i) => labels(i % labels.size)
}.mapValues(arr => arr.map(_._1).toList)

val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
println(m)
println("fill values in = " +  (t2-t1) + " msecs")
```

Please notice - there is no mutable data structures here

Comment: Heh. Just came up with exactly the same thing. It's about 1000 times faster for me.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the reason why I didn't use `grouped` or  `groupBy` it's because this code crash if the number of points is greater than one million.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the right approach is to change away from functional style. 
I have written a solution in c style Scala.

```
def main(args : Array[String]) = {
val labels = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6")
val points = Array.fill(600000){0.0}


val numChannels=6;
val channels=new Array[Array[Double]](numChannels);
for(i<-0 until numChannels){
  channels(i)=new Array[Double]((points.length/6));
}

var from=0;

val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis

for(i<-0 until numChannels){
  val channel=channels(i);
  from=i
  var to=0;
  try{
    while(true){
      channel(to)=points(from);
      to=to+1;
      from=from+numChannels;
    }
  } catch {
    case e:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException =>{
      //Ok finished this channel
    }
  }
}

val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis

println("fill values in = " +  (t2-t1) + " msecs")
println("from:"+from)
}
```

This solution does only the work that needs to be done and no more.

On my mashine it uses 8 msecs.
elm's code uses 309 msecs.
The original took 221226 msecs.

While I love Scala it is important to remember that it is good at hiding the computational cost of its operations. Most operations on collections introduces at least a couple of procedure calls per element.

Comment: I understand that your code have a good performance but the problem is that I don't know the number of channels in advance, so imagine that I have 35 channels, I need to change your code ..

Comment: @alifirat, then you'll end up with code like my answer. You can pre-create the arrays of the right length instead of using ArrayBuffers which would speed things up a bit.

Comment: This gives arrays that are `1 element too long if the points array length is a mulltiple of 6.

Comment: Yes. The arrays are 1 too long and the number of arrays is fixed. The example still demonstrates that doing only the necessary work is way faster than using the scala collections style.

Comment: Updated the code to have variable number of channels.

Comment: A few runs shows mine and your latest are pretty much  the same speed.

Comment: Turned the loop to fill one channel at a time. That doubled the speed on my mashine. Maybe the processor write cache is used better?

Comment: Fixed a bug and updated the timing. I guess i ended at 8 ms

Comment: When I run the main loop between the timing points 10x, on a points array 100x as big, both your latest and mine take around 2500 ms. I suspect cache sizes and architectures are having an impact here. Your latest is also very similar to what mine does now, so that should be no surprise.

Comment: They ended up almost the same. I belive we are quite close to what is possible from inside the jvm. There is of course the option of just leaving the data where it is and implemating a iterator that lets you iterate over segments of the array. This would move some of the work into the user, but depending on the next step might be faster overall.